# How to replace a OR b using powershell command in a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace

I want to replace a string in a file with another string. However, the string to find could be one of two values.

Example:

'cool' changed to 'fun'

'uncool' changed to 'fun'

It works if I only try to change one value, but when I try to change if its one OR the other, it crashes. I put a pause after but it still closes to quickly to see the red error

I **tried** altering the code to have use ForEach-Object and multiple replace, as per [How to replace multiple strings using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636506/how-to-replace-multiple-strings-using-powershell) , but it errors out

**My code**:

```
powershell -Command "(gc index.html) | ForEach-Object {
$_.replace('desktop', 'es').replace('en', 'es') } | Out-File -encoding UTF8 index.html"
```

**Actual Result**: Errors out: "Missing closing '}' in statement block. At line: 1 char: 35"

But there is definitely a closing brace, as can be seen in the code displayed above.

**Expected Result**: Update the index.html file. Any place where it has either 'desktop' or 'en', change the value to 'es'

Comment: 'Errors out' isn't very descriptive. Please post the actual error that you get.

Comment: @mjsqu I'm sorry, but as I mentioned the screen immediately closes, even though I put a pause. How would you suggest getting it to stay open long enough to capture the error?

Comment: @mjsqu updated, what are your thoughts now?

Comment: Remove the line break in the command. Use the same -Encoding on the input  side. Use the RegEx based -replace operator with an alternation instead of the .replace method.  `-replace 'desktop|en','es'`

Comment: @LotPings as such? powershell -Command "(gc index.html) -replace 'desktop|en', 'es'  | Out-File -encoding UTF8 index.html"

Comment: `powershell -NoP -C "(gc index.html -raw -enc UTF8) -replace 'desktop|en', 'es' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 index.html"` It depends on your content, `en` might occur in other words, so a better RegEx is advised.

Comment: That errors with "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'raw' . What does the NoP (cant seem to find this from googling)?

Comment: Leave the `-raw` out, it'll still work, just not as quickly.

Comment: @LotPings what is NoP? I;'ve been googling for a while and couldn't find this command.

Comment: When invoking PowerShell from batch it can save time initializing using the `-NoProfile` parameter, paramter names may be abbreviated as long they are uniquely distinguishable from each other. As there also is `-NoLogo`, `-NoP` is the shortest possible abbr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alternating regex and eliminate the foreach:

```
(gc index.html) -replace 'desktop|en','es' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 index.html
```

Comment: Adding in the alternating regex is causing problems in the angular app. I tested this many times and the issue only occurs when having 'desktop|en' ... if I just have 'desktop' the issue doesn't occur, however that takes me back to square one.  The error is: webfont.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined